# Python 3 Pandas: Custom sorting a list of strings

Tags: python, pandas

I need to sort a list of strings such that "non-numeric" values are sorted alphabetically first, followed by "numeric" values, in ascending order.

For example, suppose the list is:

```
l = ['2.9', '-1', '0', 'ab2', 'xyz', 'ab']
```

I'd like the output to be:

```
sorted_l = ['ab', 'ab2', 'xyz', '-1', '0', '2.9']
```

So far, I can only do this if the strings are all "integers":

```
import functools

l=['1','0','-1','2', '-9']

def compare(x, y):
    return int(x) - int(y)

sorted_l = sorted(l, key = functools.cmp_to_key(compare))
```

It'd be even more ideal if I can do it without using functools.
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A possible solution:

```
def is_numeric(s):
  try:
    float(s)
    return True
  except ValueError:
    return False

l = ['2.9', '10', '0', 'ab2', 'xyz', 'ab']
l.sort(key=lambda x: (is_numeric(x), float(x) if is_numeric(x) else x))
```

---

Alternatively and more elegantly, we can follow @QuangHoang's suggestion:

```
def is_numeric(s):
  try:
    float(s)
    return True, float(s)
  except ValueError:
    return False, s

l = ['2.9', '100', '0', 'ab2', 'xyz', 'ab']
l.sort(key=lambda x: is_numeric(x))
```

---

Output:

```
['ab', 'ab2', 'xyz', '-1', '0', '2.9']
```

Comment: upvoted, though `'1e0` is a valid float string to Python, but not to most human...

Comment: When I put in '100' or '10' in the unsorted list, in the sorted list, it will come between 0 and 2.9

Comment: I have just fixed that in my code, @dataengineer22.

Comment: In this case just `try: return True, float(s) except: return False, s` in `is_numeric`.

Comment: Thanks, @QuangHoang! That is indeed a more elegant way! Updated my answer meanwhile.